# Grails Domain hasMany Modeling

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an Author who has many books.  A book has many chapters.  The book is published by different publishers who pay different commissions.

So, the domains will be.

```
Author { hasMany [books: Book] }
Book { hasMany [chapters: Chapter, publishers: Publisher] }
Publisher { }
```

Grails generates the **book_chapter** and **book_publisher** tables.  So far so good.
The database looks good.
Commission is a value of the type Single. But where do I put the commission?
Would you show me how to set this up please?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I give up.  I don't know how to set up the relationship between the Author, Book, and Publisher.  The idea is simple. Different publishers will pay me different commissions for my books.

I will remove the hasMany Publisher relationship from the Book.  So, my Book is just now:

```
Author { hasMany [books: Book] }
Book { hasMany [chapters: Chapter] }
Publisher { ... }
```

Now I will add a Commission domain to have my commission amount stored in the database.

```
Commission {
   Author author
   Book book
   Publisher publisher

   Float amount
}
```

Next I need to make a composite primary key with both Author, Book, and Publisher.  This will prevent duplicated records.  It is because this is not correct to have more than one record in the database to show how much the publisher pays me for the same book.

I think this will work.  What I need to do next is to program the controller to fill out the commission objects manually.

I originally don't want to think or type too much if I can use the built-in scaffolding.  Let Grails do all the heavy lifting for me.  I don't think I can use the scaffolding anymore.

Good job me.

Please leave a comment.